USB Type-C DFP Host Port implementation without Switch
I am currently designing a new board that has a four port USB 3.2 x1 Gen1 hub on it. I only need two ports and now thinkering how to best make use of the other two ports.
The idea was to make at least one port accessible by a USB Type-C connector. And now the question comes up how to connect it. The straight forward option would be using a chip like HD3SS3220 that also has the CC-Controller integrated.
But now I'm asking myself if this is even necessary? Would such a topology also work that Is drawn here? I came up with this as the Type-C Spec is talking about "Implementation without Switch" in Figure 4-3.

Or would I need to connect the USB D+/D- lines from Port 4 to the second side of the USB-C connector where also the SSRX/TX2 lines are connected?
Would it be ok in terms for the Type-C specification to just use 2x 56k pull-ups to the CC-lines for signaling default usb power hence 900mA ?
